# Buffer in ArcView/Basic vs ArcInfo/Advanced level licenses of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, buffer, basic-license-level

I have ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.

Is Buffer only available with an ArcInfo (called Advanced from 10.0) or is there a way to buffer with an ArcView (called Basic from 10.0) level license?

Comment: ArcGIS supports buffering: http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-93-whatsnew.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcGIS is the software suite name, whereas ArcView, ArcEditor, & ArcInfo are licensing levels for ArcGIS.

ArcView has limited buffer options, and ArcInfo has the full, advanced buffer options (see bullet point #4 under "Usage Tips").

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=buffer_%28analysis%29

Comment: Thanks, well I meant to say ArcView. I did the buffer as I have done it before when I had ArcInfo but now only have ArcView on my current laptop. thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: For completeness: loosely speaking, ArcGIS refers to the graphical point and click Esri GIS software, e.g. ArcMap, ArcCatalog, and ArcGIS Server while [Arcinfo Worksation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcinfo-workstation/info) is the command line application, especially when referred to as ArcINFO. The command line application is only available at the ArcInfo license level, which is where the level name comes from.

Comment: ArcToolbox->Analysis Tools->Proximity->Buffer

Answer (score 4):

Buffering is allowed in all licences (ArcView, ArcEditor & ArcInfo)

Full License Matrix for 9.3 is here:

http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis93-functionality-matrix-list.pdf